# Rails, Mongoid, Group by date, month, year on created_at, Line chart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, linechart

I need to get Array response from rails moingo cipher query.

Group By date

```
[["Mar 26, 2016", 5],["Mar 27, 2016", 5],["Mar 29, 2016",8],["Mar 30, 2016",5],["Apr 1, 2016",5]]
```

Group by year

```
[["2013", 15],["2014", 225],["2015",8],["2016",5],["2017",5]]
```

I have done same thing with ruby group_by and map, But need to do with mongo query.

Comment: Can you please provide more details

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use mongo query for group_by, you can use aggregation.
You can read more about aggregation from mongo official doc
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/

example:

```
ModalName.collection.aggregate([ { "$group": { _id: { month: {"$month": "$created_at"}, year: {"$year": "$created_at"} }, count: { "$sum": 1 } } } ] ).to_a
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use group_by(&:field_name)

```
#Model
class Flow
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title,         type: String
  field :category_name, type: String
end

# Rails console
Flow.all.group_by(&:category_name)

# Result
{"album"=>
  [#<Flow _id: ...)>,]}
```